# invalid argument #1 to 'insert' (table expected, got nil)

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to script an inventory. This is supposed to make items stack in the inventory:

```lua
local function scanItems()
    local items = {}
    
    for i, tool in pairs(backback:GetChildren()) do
        if tool.ClassName == "Tool" then
            table.insert(items, tool)
        end
    end
     
    for i, tool in pairs(char:GetChildren()) do
        if tool.ClassName == "Tool" then
            table.insert(items,tool)
        end
    end
    
    local invItems = {}
    
    for i, tool in pairs(items) do
        if invItems[tool.Name] then
            invItems[tool.Name].Count += 1
            table.insert(invItems[tool.Name].Items, tool) <--there is the issue(error is title)
        else
            invItems[tool.Name] = {
                Count = 1;
                items = {tool};
            }
        end
        
    end
    
    
    print(invItems)
end

task.wait(5)
scanItems()
```

Comment: because you are using uppercase I in items when you index it vs when you create it?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably avoid the duplication and use of `items` table by doing something similar to this (untested).

```
local function scanItems()
    local invItems = {}
    local function addInvItems(children)
        for _, tool in ipairs(children) do
            if tool.ClassName == "Tool" then
                local stack = invItems[tool.Name]
                if stack then
                    stack.Count += 1
                    table.insert(stack.Items, tool)
                else
                    invItems[tool.Name] = {
                        Count = 1,
                        Items = {tool}
                    }
                end
            end
        end
    end

    addInvItems(backback:GetChildren())
    addInvItems(char:GetChildren())

    print(invItems)
end
```

Comment: it worked very well, thanks for helping!